# SUM a list of account balances excluding a specific range of accounts

Tags: excel, vba, filter, sumifs, accounting

How would I sum a large amount of GL accounts (4,000 lines about 100 unique accounts) while excluding a specific range of accounts (about 40 unique accounts).

I want to be able to do this without manually writing out "<> XXX" 40 times for each account. Ideally I have a table of the accounts I want to not include in the sum that is referenced.

Screenshot of values I want to sum in Column H, based off accounts in Column  F while excluding the accounts in Column K.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula as array formula. Press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** after you enter formula.

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A25=H13,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2:B25,F2:F5,0)),C2:C25,0),0))
Column A - Your profit centers
Column B - Your accounts
Column C - Amounts to sum
Column F - Accounts you want to exclude
Cell H13 - Profit center that you want to sum up
```

Note: After each time you edit formula press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**.

Comment: This works great. Except I wasn't specific enough. Instead of having it take the total sum of everything, how can I have it sum on every change in plant number (Column E). To clarify...the exclusion of certain accounts works but instead of having it sum everything I would want to get the sum for every change in plant # column E.

Comment: Could you show me Column E? and be more clear ? Please first of all add some visualization of your table.

Comment: I added an updated screenshot. I will try to explain more clearly sorry I am new. The array formula you gave works but it sums all the columns in the worksheet. What I want is to do the samething but provide the sum of every profit centre (column A). For example: I would want the sum of profit centre 64010 accounts excluding the specified accounts in column G. Then I want the samething for only profit centre 64011 so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

first write in **J2**:

```
=iferror(vlookup(F2,K:K,1,false),1)
```

Then copy this formula till the end of table.

After that in cell where you want to sum, put following

```
=sumif(J:J,"1",H:H)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, data in A:B and exclusions in e1:e3

`=SUM((ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$4000,$E$1:$E$3,0)))*($B$1:$B$4000))`

This will give you the total sum - exclusions
 and this will be for certain accounts in column J

`=SUM(($A$1:$A$4000=$J4)*(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$4000,$E$1:$E$3,0)))*($B$1:$B$4000))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider an aggregate SQL query which can be run within Excel using the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files), assuming you use Excel for PC. With SQL you can filter according to `Account number` and group by `Profit Center`. No arrays or loops needed.

For your needs, you can select regions inside a worksheet to be used as tables. Be sure to add column headers and reference in SQL statement accordingly. Main columns will be main table and the do not include as the subquery table. Below setup queries data in worksheet named *DATA* and outputs results in empty worksheet named *EMPTY*.

**SQL** *(embedded below in VBA as string)*

```sql
SELECT d.[Profit Center], Sum(d.Amount) As [Sum Amount]
FROM [DATA$A:D] d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DATA$I:J] sub
                  WHERE sub.[DNI_Account number] = d.[Account number])
GROUP BY d.[Profit Center]
```

**VBA**

```
Public Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object, fld As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                          & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strSQL = " SELECT d.[Profit Center], Sum(d.Amount) As [Sum Amount]" _
                & " FROM [DATA$A:D] d " _
                & " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DATA$G:H] sub" _
                & "              WHERE sub.[Account number] = d.[Account number])" _
                & " GROUP BY d.[Profit Center]"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION AND RECORDSET
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    Worksheets("RESULTS").Activate
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A1").Activate

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a much better solution,
you can do vlookup to the list of values you want to exclude, and near to each line of the column you do want to sum just put some kind of marking to (as yes\no) than in the sumifs function just add 1 condition "from column x:x take only the values marked with "yes" and this it,
worked fine for me